# jquery drop down menu is not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery code for my drop down menu:

```
var active = 0;

   $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#dropmenu ul").css({display:"none"});
    // For 1 Level
    jQuery("#dropmenu li:has(ul) a").append('');
    jQuery("#dropmenu li ul a span").text('');
    // For 2 Level
    jQuery("#dropmenu li ul li:has(ul) a").append('');
    jQuery("#dropmenu li ul li ul a span").text('');

    jQuery("#dropmenu li").hover(function(){
    if(active != 1){
    jQuery($('.active').parent()).find("ul:first").css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(this).find("ul:first").fadeIn('fast');
    active = 1;
    }
    },
    function(){
    jQuery(this).find("ul:first").fadeOut('fast');
    jQuery($('.active').parent()).find("ul:first").fadeIn('fast');
    active = 0;
    }); });

    //ACTIVATE 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery($('.active').parent()).find("ul:first").css('display', 'block');
    });
```

What the code is suppose to do is check and see which element has an `active` class and show it when the page loads.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul id="dropmenu">
    <li><a  class="active" href="index.php">home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Euro 2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FIA Cup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Previous Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Event 2012-2013</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Pre Season</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" >home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blabl</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dropdown</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Euro 2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FIA Cup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Previous Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Event 2012-2013</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Pre Season</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

right now when the page loads the default drop down is shown however once you hover over other menu items if they dont have a drop down menu it shows the default one and hides, and if you quickly go over the the menu item it will keep repeating the animation. How can I avoid the repetition of the animation and how can I avoid showing the default menu when the menu is empty?

Comment: I guarantee you there's a better way to come up with a line of code than this `jQuery("#dropmenu li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a span").text('');`.

Comment: thats for levels of drop menu, I am only using one level anyways, so thats not important

Comment: If you are not using the code, delete it. At least remove it from your question, questions should only have the code that is relevant. http://sscce.org

Comment: done, now I would appreciate a solution.

Comment: I have added a fiddle so everyone can debug http://jsfiddle.net/reu43/.

Comment: appreciate it, the demo above is exactly the problem I am having

Comment: i say scrap this and look for scripts that do that, there are plenty if you just take the time to google, here is a useful link :
http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-drop-down-menus/

Answer (score 1):

I say scrap this and look for scripts that do that, there are plenty if you just take the time to google, here is a useful link :

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-drop-down-menus

I personally use this plugin to make dropdown menus:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

You can do a lot with this plugin with a little help of html and css to make a row of dropdown menus... The plugin uses jQuery and jQuery UI for the design, you can custom it however you want, here is the link  to the jQueryUI website if you haven't been there: http://www.jqueryui.com/themeroller